# Haskell how to construct object having dependent types

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I have used type family in the data 'D' to constraint the type of first item in it.
Now I need to create object of either type 'D B1' or 'D B2' from some common functions (like intermediate_func). But the below code does not work.
Any suggestions how to do this? or to put similar constraints in another manner.

```
data A1 = A1
data A2 = A2

data B1 = B1
data B2 = B2

data C a b where
  C1 :: Int →  C a b
  C2 :: Char →  C A1 b
  C3 :: Bool →  C A1 B1

type family ResT b where
  ResT B1 = C A1 B1
  ResT B2 = C A2 B2

data D b where
  D1 :: ResT B1 →  C A1 B1 →  D B1
  D2 :: ResT b →  C A1 b →  D b

-- This does not compile
intermediate_func :: Int →  D b
intermediate_func i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)

-- This works
-- intermediate_func :: Int -> D B2
-- intermediate_func i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
-- So does this
-- intermediate_func :: Int -> D B1
-- intermediate_func i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a proof that `b` is either `B1` or `B2`, and not anything else. As written, one might call `intermediate_func :: Int →  D String`.

You can pass such proof through a singleton:

```
data S b where
   SB1 :: S B1
   SB2 :: S B2

intermediate_func :: S b → Int →  D b
intermediate_func SB1 i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
intermediate_func SB2 i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
```

If you want to hide the singleton argument of type `S b`, check out [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34575361/3234959). You can achieve that using type classes. E.g.

```
class CB b where getSB :: S b
instance CB B1 where getSB = SB1
instance CB B2 where getSB = SB2

intermediate_func :: SB b → Int → D b
intermediate_func SB1 i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
intermediate_func SB2 i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)

intermediate_func_short :: CB b => Int → D b
intermediate_func_short = intermediate_func getSB
```

Comment: Thanks chi! this works. But I would really like to not put this in every API. So using type classes would be much better. I tried to implement one using the answer you gave in another post, but still could not understand how to do it :( Can you post an answer using type classes also ?

Comment: I tried to get something like this to work `intermediate_func :: (IsB b) => Int -> D b`

Comment: I think I understand why, but I still find it a bit disappointing that [using data kinds to restrict the domain of `RestT` to `B1` or `B2` doesn't satisfy the proof obligation](https://gist.github.com/rampion/704d3b906e937b931793)

Comment: @rampion Indeed. In a true dependently typed language you could pattern match over the kind. In Haskell we need auxiliary singletons / type classes, which is more burdensome.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using type classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}                                                                                             
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}                                                                                      
module Temp where                                                                                                  

data A1                                                                                                            
data A2                                                                                                            
data B1                                                                                                            
data B2                                                                                                            

data C a b where                                                                                                   
  C1 :: Int ->  C a b                                                                                              
  C2 :: Char ->  C A1 b                                                                                            
  C3 :: Bool ->  C A1 B1                                                                                           

class Intermediate b where                                                                                         
  type ResT b                                                                                                      
  intermediate_func :: Int ->  D b                                                                                 

data D b where                                                                                                     
  D1 :: ResT B1 ->  C A1 B1 ->  D B1                                                                               
  D2 :: ResT b ->  C A1 b ->  D b                                                                                  

instance Intermediate B1 where                                                                                     
  type ResT B1 = C A1 B1                                                                                           
  intermediate_func i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)                                                                           

instance Intermediate B2 where                                                                                     
  type ResT B2 = C A2 B2                                                                                           
  intermediate_func i = D2 (C1 i) (C1 i)
```